# JQuery noConflict issue for 2 different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone could guide me to write Jquery noConflict for the below two different functions please? One function is for sticky header & another one is for search pop-up.

Header:-

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');

        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Search:-

```
function openSearch() {
      $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(); // "500" is not required. "400" is the default value
  }

  function closeSearch() {
      $("#myOverlay").fadeOut();  // "500" is not required. ""400 is the default value
  }
```

Comment: What conflict are you referring to?

Comment: JQuery noConflict - Those two functions are not working due to the $ conflict. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Wrap everything in `(function($){ /* your code /*})(jQuery)`. Is also shown in `$.noConflict` docs